# pygame loaded image used in tkinter "doesn't exist"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

First of all I'm fairly new with Python and I acknowledge that my code is unorganized. Relating to the actual question though, basically I loaded an image to a variable using pygame. I am using that image in a toplevel in tkinter. When I attempt to use the image in a label on that toplevel, it says that it doesn't exist. I'm using a module that I created in some areas, but I don't think it would have any relation, so I'm not including it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from myfunctions import *
import pygame



master = tk.Tk()
master.resizable(0,0)

info = "Guess a number between \n 1 and 99 inclusive!"


f=tk.Frame(master, width=500, height=450)
f.pack_propagate(0)
f.pack()

l=tk.Label(f, text=info, font=("Arial", 30))
l.pack()

heat=tk.Label(f, font=("Arial", 24), fg="red", pady=30)
heat.pack()

f2= tk.Frame(f)
f2.pack()

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(f2, from_= 1, to = 99)
spinbox.pack()

bframe=tk.Frame(f, pady =30)
bframe.pack()

def itsago():
    valid = validcheck(spinbox.get())
    if valid == 0:
        heat.config(text="Not a valid input")
        heat.pack()
    else:
        hcheck = hiddencheck(valid)
        heat.config(text=hcheck)
        heat.pack()
        if hcheck == "You won!\n Re-Open the program to play again.":
            pwin= tk.Toplevel()
            pwin.resizable(0, 0)
            sloth = pygame.image.load('paradesloth.png')
            lparade = tk.Label(pwin, anchor = "nw")
            lparade.config(image = sloth)
            lparade.image = sloth
            lparade.pack()
            pwin.mainloop()


b = tk.Button(bframe, command = itsago, text="Check Number", font=("Arial", 20),       bg="white")
b.pack()



master.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

*EDIT: forgot to add one of the most important things, the error:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "<Surface(800x599x24 SW)>" doesn't exist
```

Comment: `pygame.image.load()` returns a `pygame.surface` object, which is not the same thing as a `tk.PhotoImage` object -- they're not interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). pygame's image load is more convenient for me as tk.PhotoImage only seems to support gifs. Is there any way I could integrate pygame's image loader or should I just convert the image to a gif?

Comment: Never mind, converted to gif and it looks just fine. For some reason PhotoImage wasn't working for me yesterday, but apperantly I made some sort of change which fixed the real issue. Thanks very much martineau! :)

Comment: [`PIL`](http://effbot.org/downloads/#pil) has an [`ImageTK`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) module that can create `tk.PhotoImage` objects and `PIL` supports the [.png format](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/format-png.htm). See [The Python Imaging Library Handbook](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/) for more information. Got all that? ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using python 3.3 though and I don't believe PIL supports it yet :)

Comment: For Python 3 you can use [`pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0) instead of `PIL`. It's better is several other respects, too.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by martineau in the comments:

> pygame.image.load() returns a pygame.surface object, which is not the same thing as a tk.PhotoImage object -- they're not interchangeable. – martineau 8 mins ago